# SQL transaction and tables SELECT LOCK clarification

Tags: php, mysql, database, postgresql, transactions

I have a question regarding online transactions and want to clarify the below issue with `SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries.

I will use the below example to explain this to you.

X is doing an online transaction. His account balance is `$1000`. He is going to buy $200 item and after that his account balance should be `$800`.  That is fine; now let me elaborate this further

```
Begin DB transaction.

Step 1: account balance is $1000

{Select the balance from a different script}

Step 2: Buy something for $200

{Select the balance from another script}

Step 3: Remaining balance $800

Commit DB transaction
```

As you can see in between step 1 and 3 the balance has been checked by a different query outside the transaction and another script is checking balance again within step 2 and 3.

1. With default Mysql transactions what will be the values for first
   and second balance results? Also by default is Mysql using `“SELECT
   ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE” or “SELECT ... FOR UPDATE”` features or do
   we have to use them within our queries.
2. If we need to return $800 for both balance check queries above by
   waiting for the transaction to commit which method can we use Eg:
   “`SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE” or “SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`”
3. Also do you know if Mysql and Post greSql handles the
   transactions differently as mentioned above?

Answer (score 3):

In both MySQL (with InnoDB) and PostgreSQL, using READ COMMITTED or SERIALIZABLE isolation mode, the balance will be the same at step 2 and step 3. The change will only be visible after transaction commit.

MySQL with MyISAM might be different, but you should not be using it if you care about data correctness or consistency.

Neither MySQL nor PostgreSQL will do a `FOR SHARE` or `FOR UPDATE` unless you specifically request it.

Both PostgreSQL and MySQL (InnoDB) should behave similarly in READ COMMITTED mode. For the details of PostgreSQL's behaviour see the [manual on transaction isolation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html).

If you want to get 800 for both reads, as described above, there are two things you must do:

- The updating transaction must `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` the balance record for the user before `INSERT`ing the transaction record and `UPDATE`ing the balance; and
- The reading transaction ("other script") must `SELECT ... FOR SHARE` the balance whenever it reads it, so it will wait whenever somebody else is updating it instead of just reading the unchanged version.

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks for the detail - I have a question though. What if the "other script" simply does a SELECT? In a web application, we may have many scripts SELECTing data but perhaps one main script doing the SELECT FOR UPDATE as you describe. If the "other script" just does a SELECT, will it WAIT for the update transaction to finish, or will it simply read the value it needs? (e.g. $1000 in the above example). If it reads $1000, then how can the UPDATE script "lock" the tables to stop this? (in the case where you have many other scripts reading that data).

Comment: FYI, I understand the "other script" must do a SELECT FOR SHARE to get the correct data. But my question is when you are introducing a new SELECT FOR UPDATE to a web application that already has many other "reading" scripts doing a SELECT (and not a SELECT FOR SHARE). Is the only answer to identify and update all the other "reading" scripts to use SELECT FOR SHARE?

Comment: @rishijd If you can't fix the reading applications, you must `LOCK TABLE ... IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE` before starting the update. This prevents everything else from reading or writing the table.

Comment: @rishijd but really, the reading scripts are wrong and need fixing. They should be using `FOR SHARE` if they want to see a value that cannot be concurrently updated.